# Is there a way to avoid the `Identifier 'x' has already been declared` error in JS Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, jupyter-notebook

I seem to spend a lot of time restarting the javascript kernel for my JS Jupyter Notebooks. Any time I have a line such as `let svg = dom.window.document.getElementById('seal')` and I change that line in any way, running it again always gets me a `SyntaxError: Identifier 'svg' has already been declared` even though it is only declared in that cell. I suppose this has something to do with the cell (or notebook) caching the variable? But it eats up a lot of time to have to constantly restart the kernel to get around the error. Is there any other method of avoiding this error?

Comment: Use `var` instead?